Learning a probability distribution from samples drawn from unknown function
I am wanting to learn some probability distribution $p$ from data (using e.g., Kernel Density Estimation, a Normalizing Flow, whatever your favourite machine learning model is).
If I had a dataset $D = [x_1, \dots , x_N]$, where $x_{[0,\dots,N]} \sim p(x)$, and if I was training some model $\hat{p}_{\theta}$ (where $\theta$ are the model parameters), I would do something like minimize the negative log likelihood, i.e., optimize:
$$\arg\min_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[-\log \hat{p}_{\theta}(x)]$$
where
$$\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[-\log\hat{p}_\theta(x)] \approx \sum_{i=0}^{N} -\log \hat{p}_{\theta}(x_i)$$
However, I am currently in a situation where I do not know the distribution the data was drawn from, but do have access to the likelihoods of each data point under p. That is, I have:
$$D = [\langle x_1, p(x_1)\rangle, \dots \langle x_N, p(x_N)\rangle]$$
Where I do not know the distribution under which $x_1, \dots x_N$ were generated (Specifically, a large number of samples were generated from some unknown biased distribution, then a subset of those "good" samples were collected by an experimenter via a deterministic Sequential Bayesian Optimization process, then the likelihoods $p(x_i)$ were computed via some expensive simulation).
Can I still learn something about $p$ in this situation?
As a side note, I know that if I knew what the other distribution was (lets say $x_i$ were generated by q(x)), I could learn something via importance sampling. I.e., I could optimize:
$$\arg \min_{\theta} E_{q(x)}[-\log \hat{p}_{\theta}(x)\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}]$$
But given that I have strictly less information than this...can I still do anything with the data?

is very unclear which is the biased/unbiased distribution... are $x_i$s drawn from the unbiased or not?

@Alberto It is admittedly an unclear setup: I am trying to learn the distribution $p$, but the $x_i$s are not drawn from p. They are drawn from some (unknown) biased distribution. However, what I do have are the likelihood values $p(x_i)$ for each data point. I.e., I have some information about the likelihood I would have seen each $x_i$ under the target distribution.
If it makes it any easier, lets at least assume that we know the $x_i$s are drawn from some distribution with the same support as $p$.

what about learning $q$ (the biased distribution), and then learn $p$ with IS? at that point, you have a likelihood estimate for $q$ supposedly
